# типизация через Record не совместима с конкретным ключом?

Tags: typescript

как решить данную ситуацию? Хочется получить интерфейс в котором есть одни единственный ключь типо `number`, и много других типо `boolean` как вариант;

> Property 'some' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'boolean'

```
type TType = Record<string, boolean>;

interface IProps extends TType {
   some?: number;
}
```

вариант с `type TType = Record<string, boolean | number>;` не подходит так как единственный тип с `number` это ключь `some`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желаемый тип можно объявить так:

```
type IProps = {
  some?: number
} & {
  [key in string]?: key extends "some" ? number : boolean 
}
```

После этого переменные такого типа можно полноценно использовать.

Но есть проблема: присвоить переменной этого типа литеральный объект с полем `some`, отличным от `undefined`, тайпскрипт без явного приведения не позволит. А вот поменять значение поля уже существующей переменной можно без проблем.

---

Однако, по названию у меня сложилось впечатление, что речь о реакт-компонентах, а там можно нахимичить с дженериками: [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnAHgGk4kAPGJAHYATFnBYwowAQHMAfHAC8cAN7k4Y3EgD8ALjgCAriABGSKOQC+cAGQq1cANoBrJNThS4AUR5oANgaEkTgAaOAAiFk0w2QBdPWMICF9UAUtKTAMBDGAIATgAZRAYAAs2ABVZAAowZhY9MptGWrZxSRlGl2oITDgKgEo7dSIYAyg8w19fNPIMrJgcvIBBMDBKgdUhpBGxuEr7dTZZffU4NkKSuAB6I5OTs6LijRAkBWUAFgAmK2vjg-PHgCOQNeEgMSG+N1up3+Txe7y+cCBAJBUDBEOObB+6j6aSAA)

```
import React from 'react';

type Props<K extends string> = {
  some?: number
} & {
  [key in Exclude<K, "some">]: boolean
}

function Smth<T>(props: T & Props<string & keyof T>) {
  return null
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Smth />
      <Smth some={42} />
      <Smth qqq={true} />
      <Smth some={42} qqq={true} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Спаасиб) то что надо

Answer (score -1):

Да, проблема в том, что типизация через Record<string, boolean> не совместима с конкретным ключом some.

Одно из возможных решений - использовать объединение типов с помощью "|". Таким образом, можно задать тип IProps следующим образом:

```typescript
type TType = Record<string, boolean>;

interface IProps extends TType {
   some?: number;
   [key: string]: boolean | number | undefined;
}
```

Теперь IProps содержит ключ some с типом number, а также другие ключи с типом boolean или number, которые могут быть добавлены в объект.

Такой интерфейс позволяет создать объект со свойством some типа number и другими свойствами типа boolean:

```typescript
const props: IProps = {
   some: 42,
   flag1: true,
   flag2: false,
   flag3: undefined,
};
```

Comment: ты описал тоже что и `type TType = Record<string, boolean | number | undefined>;` а смысл? я тоже что то не знаю способ, но это точно не решение

Comment: чот да, только заметил. Не поможет тут объединение типов, а если так попробовать?

interface IProps {
  some?: number;
  [key: string]: boolean | undefined;
}

Как то это по умному даже называется помойму

Comment: не помогает к сожелению, но спасибо за старания помочь.